# Unable to cast code first

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, code-first

Having this class that represents model

```
public class User : IHaveId
{
    public User()
    {
        Operations = new Collection<Operation>();
    }
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string CardNumber { get; set; }
    public string Pin { get; set; }
    public double Balance { get; set; }
    public bool Blocked { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Operation> Operations { get; set; }


}
```

and this seed method in my own Initializer:

```
    protected override void Seed(BankContext context)
    {
        var users = MockData.GetUsers();
        foreach (var user in users)
        {
            user.Operations.Add(
                    new Operation
                    {
                        OperationType = OperationType.Balance,
                        PerformTime = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-10)
                    }
            );

            user.Operations.Add(
                    new Operation
                    {
                        OperationType = OperationType.GetMoney,
                        PerformTime = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-5),
                        AdditionInformation = "800"
                    }
            );

            context.Users.Add(user);
        }
        base.Seed(context);
    }
```

Having exception at Add stage saying: Unable cast `Collection<Operation>` to Operation.
Can someone explain why this happening?

Do i need to specify anything special in onModelCreating for this case?

Comment: Unable cast Collection<Operation> to Operation? it seems that you are assigning collection of operation to single operation that is not possible.

Comment: Yes, that is why i'm here

Comment: Code in the question seems working ok.

Comment: Is there any EF configurations that prevent may cause such errors?

Comment: Is there a specific reason you assign Operations in the constructor? If it's one to many relation, EF will create it correctly. I think you can remove the whole User constructor.

Comment: @Sami, is usefull when you create a new user (so you can just add the operations). In this case (when you create a new user) EF doesn't do anything.

Comment: @Valentyn Vynogradskiy if you use lazy load mark the collection as virtual (but this won't solve your problem). How did you map Operations and users? Is the DbSet ok?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `User.Operations` is supposed to be a collection property (and not a reference property), you need to use `HasMany`:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
    .HasMany(a => a.Operations)
    .WithOptional()
    .WillCascadeOnDelete(true);
```

Originally, you were telling EF that `User.Operations` is a reference property, which causes an error when you try to assign a collection to it.

Answer (score 0):

Okey, i found the issue, 
As i thought there was a reason outside of the posted code. 
In my BankContext class i have

```
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {

        modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
            .HasOptional(a => a.Operations)
            .WithOptionalDependent()
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(true);
    }
```

That some how influent on this. Can anyone explain how that influent?

Comment: If you have a new question it is better  to open a new one

Comment: Just to avoid the next question, don't forget to mark public ICollection<Operation> Operations { get; set; }
 as virtual